# Does any body have any idea what is this error in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, png, jpeg

I have just gone mad solving this error. But every time the error remains there.

Someone please help

[image]

Comment: Please keep the error message in text, otherwise it won't be searchable, meaning it won't be of much help to others having the same problem in the future (which is kind of the idea behind StackOverflow).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two resource files with the same base name:

- header_icon.png
- header_icon.jpg

Delete one of them.

Comment: The two lines above the error in your screenshot tell otherwise.

Comment: i'm sorry.. you were correct... i just found the JPEG file and deleted that and every thing is fine.... Thanks buddy